# Programmatically push to view controller [2] in a navigation stack, and unwind to [1]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I have a `UITableViewController` populated with a list of users. The `UITableViewController` is embedded in a navigation controller. Tapping a row in the table view pushes the view controller `userVC`. Tapping the a `+` button on `userVC` pushes a view controller `addAlarmVC`. (See image below)

**DEFAULT BEHAVIOR**

[image: Default Behavior]

**QUICK ACTION**

[image: Quick Action Behavior]

I want to implement a quick action from my users table view that will allow me to programmatically push `addAlarmVC` directly, and unwind or "go back" to `userVC`. I want to have both navigation routes, Default, and Quick Action.

Essentially, my question is: In a navigation stack with [0,1,2] how do I push from 0 to 2 in a way that allows me to unwind to 1? I am using storyboards, but if the problem can be solved programmatically I would prefer such.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ( give each VC a storyboard identifier in IB and load it )

```
let userVC =  ////// self.storyboard.instan
let addAlarmVC =  ////// self.storyboard.instan
self.navigationController.setViewControllers([self,userVC,addAlarmVC],animated:true)
```